# getting Laravel running on a VM on imac

Tags: php, virtual-machine, laravel-5, homestead

I am trying to get Laravel running on a Virtual Machine on my Imac running Yosemite. I have already set up my VM on my Macbook but for some reason I am having trouble getting the virtual machine working on my Imac. I believe I have all the directory paths correct but when I ssh into the VM none of my directories show up. I believe it is something to do with my directory paths but I have them routed exactly as I do on my Macbook and it still doesn't seem to work. I also get these two errors when I run "vagrant up" but from what Ive researched that shouldn't be the issue.

```
/opt/vagrant/bin/../embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/pre-rubygems.rb:31: 
warning: Insecure world writable dir /Users/tylerfoulkes in PATH, mode 040777

/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/bundler-1.7.11/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:222: warning: Insecure world writable dir   
/Users/tylerfoulkes in PATH, mode 040777
```

Homestead.yaml file

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
- ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: /Users/username/laravel
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: learn.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/laravel/public

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local

# blackfire:
    #     - id: foo
    #       token: bar
```

hosts file

```
## 
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
## 
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
127.0.0.1       learn.app
```

Comment: `folders:
    - map: /Users/username/laravel
      to: /home/vagrant/Code`

Maybe you should change that to your own username.

Comment: @AmarSyla I have that set as my username, I just used username as a general placeholder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sites folder should point to /home/vagrant/Code/public not /home/vagrant/Code/laravel/public because youare mapping the laravel folder on to Code not in to a sub directory.

```
folders:
    - map: /Users/username/laravel
      to: /home/vagrant/Code
sites:
    - map: learn.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/public
```

Or if you want laravel in a sub directory

```
folders:
    - map: /Users/username/laravel
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/laravel

sites:
    - map: learn.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/laravel/public
```

Unless of course the laravel directory contains a bunch of different laravel projects in which case it would look more like...

```
folders:
    - map: /Users/username/laravel
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: project.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/project/public
    - map: project2.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/project2/public
```